# Android: How can I force a layout or any view to have a fixed size in dip?

Tags: android, layout, view, size

Is it possible to force a layout to have a fixed size in dip?

Either a View directly or using a layout forced to have a fixed size in dip and put the view inside the layout?

And how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set specific width to the Layout you want using

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

You can do it in both way. directly to the View as well as put the View inside a Layout

Comment: Putting the View in the Layout did the trick, while specifying layout_with on the view not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible, You just need to declare the required height and width of the view or layout in xml file as below

```
android:layout_width="200dip" <!--use this instead of wrap_content or fill_parent-->
android:layout_height="200dip"
```